# Conditional #define based on another defined symbol

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is it possible in **C**/C++ to nest a preprocessor `#define` (in this case `#ifdef`)? I'd like to be able to do this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG_
#define __DEV_MODE_VERBOSE__  // Defined in DEBUG mode only
#endif
```

The idea is that "`__DEV_MODE_VERBOSE__`" will usually be commented out. When uncommented, I can use something like:

```
#ifdef __DEV_MODE_VERBOSE__
int test = (5 * GetTickCount());  // Not reached!
#endif      // __DEV_MODE_VERBOSE__
```

to log commands sent and received over my comms link. If the `#define` were accidentally left uncommented, though, the logging would NOT occur in RELEASE (and therefore production) code.

When I try to define "`__DEV_MODE_VERBOSE__`" as above, it isn't defined so I'm not sure if the syntax is incorrect or whether the problem is more fundamental. The symbol **is** defined if I don't nest between "`#ifdef _DEBUG_`" and its' `#endif`.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It should work like you did.

Comment: Should work and this is commonly done. Check your include order.

Comment: Names containing double underscores or beginning with an underscore and uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation for any use, including macros.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Thanks for that comment. When I changed "__ DEV_MODE_VERBOSE __" to "DEV_MODE_VERBOSE" it worked. Never knew about the reserved rule about double underscores! If you add an answer about that, I'll accept.

Comment: @JBentley: The question clearly states this was tested and moreover contains enough information reproduce. The problem was the invalid symbol name which TartanLlama pointed out.

Comment: @JBentley: The question has been modified in response to your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `N3337 [global.names]:` Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> — **Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.**
>
> — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
> global namespace.

Your macro contains a double underscore, so is reserved to the implementation. Changing it to a valid name should fix your issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Although I mostly code in Delphi and C# these days, I've been dabbling in C/C++ for years...and never knew this. After changing my symbol name it worked.